# How to access controls instance in react-three-fiber?

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-hooks, react-three-fiber

Is there any way to access the `controls` instance of the scene in `react-three-fiber`?

I know it can be accesed using a ref like:

```
import { useFrame } from 'react-three-fiber'

const controls = useRef()
useFrame(state => controls.current.update())
return <orbitControls ref={controls} />
```

But I am looking for some kind of global access like:

```
    const { 
        gl,         // WebGL renderer
        scene,      // Default scene
        camera,     // Default camera
    } = useThree()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it out of the box.

One way to achieve something like the `useThree` example, is to store the controls ref in a Context, and then you should be able to use it consuming that Context in any descendant of the component tree.

For example (keep in mind I didn't test this code):

```
const ControlsContext = createContext()

const ControlsContainer = ({ children }) => {
  const controls = useRef()
  return (
    <ControlsContext.Provider value={{ controls: controls.current }}>
      <orbitControls ref={controls} />
      {children}
    </ControlsContext.Provider>
  )
}

const YourComponent = () => {
  const { controls } = useContext(ControlsContext)
  // do whatever you need, but remember to check if it's defined
}

const App = () => (
  <ControlsContainer>
    <YourComponent />
  </ControlsContainer>
)
```

However I don't think this is a good practice. You probably want to keep all your controller code in one component. And in the case you need to share it to another component you could simply pass it down in a prop.

Comment: Yep, using context was my plan B. I suppose its the only way, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Drei's `OrbitControl`

```
<OrbitControls makeDefault />
```

it exposes the default control in a global state https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/blob/503f4f7b9a715dfdd33b9d0a07e6f08b93894903/src/core/OrbitControls.tsx#L100

So accessing it should be

```
const { get } = useThree();
const control = get().controls
```